General formula of Poynting vector
My question regards the actual definition of the Poynting vector. Although in vacuum and linear materials we can write $\textbf B=\mu \mathbf H$ and so there is no doubt that $\mathbf S=\frac{\mathbf E \times \mathbf B}{\mu}=\mathbf E \times \mathbf H$; what about non-linear materials like conductors or even media with frequency dependnat properties? In other words: what is the most general formula for the Poynting vector?

Does this answer your question? Poynting Vectors and Feigel Effects

Does non-linearity include anisotropy?

@naturallyInconsistent This question is a basic question from EM theory and has nothing to do with that answer. The answer there does not address this question.

@naturallyInconsistent The question does not mention or necessarily imply the Abraham-Minkowski controversy, which is about the "correct" density of EM energy and momentum. The question is about what the Poynting vector is, which is independent of that discussion. I try to make clear the Poynting vector is well-defined, but density of energy flux isn't. I don't claim my answer is definitive, but allowing different answers is helpful to people trying to understand this topic.

@JánLalinský and then that is just wrong. We all agree that Poynting theorem is correct and generally applicable. The controversy, however, necessarily intrudes into this, simply because the very definition of the Poynting vector is chosen in order for it to agree with EM energy and momentum, and it is precisely this that the controversy tells us is controversial. That you are unable to see this, makes it a problem on your part.

@naturallyInconsistent That may be your conviction, but my point is the linked answer above does not answer the question. So please find another answer that answers this question, or reopen.

@naturallyInconsistent Also, I don't believe the controversy is about what the Poynting vector is in material media. It is about what the "correct" expression for EM momentum density is. This "correct" expression need not, and often is not, and certainly should not, be called the Poynting vector, unless someone proves they should be defined to be  the same. It would be weird to call Poynting vector something whose definition in terms of EM fields is a subject of controversy, when Poynting did not partake in it, and provided clear definition of what we call the Poynting vector.

Sorry for the delay. @naturallyInconsistent, I think that the Feigel effect seems a very interesting topic (although I admit the details fly over my head). However, my question was much simpler and (because of my own defect) much stupider. My question was just about the definition of Poytning vector as Poynting defined it, indipendently from the fact that this quantity will describe correctly the momentum density of EM waves.
In other words: immagine you have a problem that gives you E, B, H and mu and asks for the Poynting vector, what formula should you use?

The Poynting theorem and the Poynting vector is unique, but definition of EM energy density and EM energy density flux isn't. There is the original Poynting analysis which works well for linear non-dissipative media, but has some deficiencies, and does not work at all when there is no functional relation between $\mathbf E,\mathbf D$ and $\mathbf B,\mathbf H$. Then there are many alternative viewpoints, one of which I'll describe below.
In the traditional Poynting way, we differentiate between the conduction current and other kinds of current (polarization current, magnetization current), and consider work of electric field only on the conduction current. The Poynting theorem, valid in linear media, is
$$
\mathbf j\cdot \mathbf E = -\partial_t\left(\frac{1}{2}\mathbf E\cdot \mathbf D + \frac{1}{2}\mathbf B\cdot\mathbf H\right) -\nabla\cdot(\mathbf E\times\mathbf H).
$$
where $\mathbf j$ is the conduction current only.
This theorem allows interpretation in terms of energy - there is the term
$$
w = \frac{1}{2}\mathbf E\cdot \mathbf D + \frac{1}{2}\mathbf B\cdot\mathbf H
$$
depending on $\mathbf E,\mathbf D,\mathbf B,\mathbf H$, which we can use to define EM energy density, and the term
$$
\mathbf S = \mathbf E\times \mathbf H,
$$
which can be interpreted as giving EM energy flux density. This term is called, irrespective of the fact whether the Poynting theorem above holds, the Poynting vector. In non-linear media, and especially in dissipative media where $\mathbf D$ is not a function of $\mathbf E$, the above Poynting theorem does not hold, thus the Poynting vector need not give correctly density of EM energy flux there.
These traditional definitions of EM energy and EM energy flux density have, with hindsight from microscopic theory of polarization/magnetization,  also the deficiency that even in linear media, part of the Poynting EM energy density is actually function of matter state variables (due to $\mathbf D, \mathbf H$), thus need not really have the same value as the average value of EM energy density in the microscopic theory.
A different problem is whether the Poynting vector always describes correctly density of flux of EM energy. In dissipative material media, the time derivative terms like $\mathbf E\cdot \frac{\partial \mathbf D}{\partial t}$ can't be written as time derivative of a function of fields $\mathbf E,\mathbf D,\mathbf B,\mathbf H$, thus definition of EM energy as above is problematic and $\mathbf S$ is not necessarily the correct description of EM energy flow.
All these issues point to the fact that the traditional Poynting treatment is not applicable in general.
The other way is to ignore the distinction between conduction current and polarization current and magnetization current, and treat all currents equally (let's denote net current $\mathbf J$). Then, from Maxwell's equations, with no need to assume linear non-dissipative medium, we can derive the theorem
$$
\mathbf J\cdot \mathbf E = - \partial_t\left(\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0 E^2 + \frac{1}{2\mu_0}B^2 \right) -\nabla \cdot(\mathbf E\times \mathbf B/\mu_0).
$$
This theorem is formally very similar to Poynting's theorem, and can be used, just as Poynting's theorem, to define density of EM energy. We can define density of EM energy
$$
w'  = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0 E^2 + \frac{1}{2\mu_0}B^2 
$$
and density of EM energy flux
$$
\mathbf S' = \mathbf E\times \mathbf B/\mu_0.
$$
We can see that values of these densities $w',\mathbf S'$ are the same as values of densities $w,\mathbf S$ in the traditional treatment when in vacuum, but differ when in material medium.
This alternative treatment with definitions $w',\mathbf S'$ has the advantage that EM energy quantities are functions of EM fields only (no matter state variables are in them) and the theorem the definitions $w',\mathbf S'$ obey holds universally in vacuum and all media, as it follows directly from Maxwell's equations in terms of $\mathbf E,\mathbf B$ and total current $\mathbf J$. These properties are not attained in the traditional treatment. Thus, in this sense, the latter treatment and definitions are preferable.

I'm quite confident the most general formula for Poynting's vector is precisely its definition. I understand from your post that you want to find some values for the electric and magnetic field such that, by introducing them in the definition of Poynting's vector, you get some sort of formula. Nontheless, this is not useful at all, since there is no such thing as an "electric field for everything". When working in electromagnetism, I suggest you proceed as follows: firstly, choose your system / phenomenon of interest. Then, you can find the electric and magnetic fields (perhaps the radiation vector would be a better choice if you are working with radiating systems). There's plenty of ways you could do this, depending on how much precision you want and how much time you'd like to invest in determining these fields (you can work analytically, computationally, it depends on your needs and interests). Finally, after you calculate the fields, you can now calculate Poynting's vector with ease. The fundamental problem of EM is to calculate the electric and magnetic fields, if there were a formula for every single scenario, then EM would be a finished science.

Mathematically, Poynting's vector is defined as you wrote it. What's your doubt about? Is it about the Physical meaning of this vector?

I am not sure I understand what you said. My question was more: "what is the actual definition of the Poynting vector" and not how to find the EM fields. Most books start introducing the Poytning vector in the case of vacuum $\mathbf S=\frac{\mathbf E\times \mathbf B}{\mu_0}$ from which it follows that $\mathbf S=\mathbf E\times \mathbf H$. However this doesn't hold for every material where $\mathbf B \ne \mu_0 \mathbf H$.  Are you saying that the two definitions of the Poynting vector in the original question are LOCALLY the same since you can always define a local $\mu$?

Oh right! Poynting's vector is defined as $\vec{S}\equiv \vec{E}\times \vec{H}$ always. Check out Maxwell's equations in material media, you'll see they involve $\vec{H}$, not $\vec{B}$, since it's easier to calculate. You don't need to invoke locality, you just need to take definitions as what they are, definitions
